# Benchmarking Database Management Systems Queries

Tags: sql, database, performance, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I am benchmarking analytical queries for many database systems. Measuring the performance is either reported by the system (like Postgres with ANALYZE option) or can be measured with the difference of time between timestamps after and before the query execution.

Many formats could be used for measuring a query performance:

> ```
> Option 1: 
>       SELECT col FROM .... # Runtime + Output results
> Option 2: 
>       PERFORM SELECT col FROM .... # Runtime and ignore results
> Option 3: 
>       INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT col FROM ... # Runtime + Insertion
> ```

Which option should be used for measuring a query execution?

Comment: Hi - why not just use the publicly available benchmarks that everyone else uses?

Comment: @NickW Like what?

Comment: tpc.org, for one

Comment: I want to benchmark different sort of systems/queries.